# Rails 3.2 HTTP streaming fails (Thin server on Windows)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, http, http-headers, streaming

I'm trying to get my pages to stream but I'm getting the following error:

Error 321 (net::ERR_INVALID_CHUNKED_ENCODING): Unknown error

I've tried in both Chrome, IE and Firefox.

```
def login
    redirect_to_stored and return if session[:user]
    if request.post?
        if session[:user] = User.authenticate(params[:login], params[:password])
            redirect_to_stored(notice: 'Login successful') and return
        else
            flash_now :alert => "Login unsuccessful"
        end
    end
    on_document_load "$('#login').focus();"
    render :layout => 'login', :stream => true
end
```

I get the following response headers:

```
Cache-Control:must-revalidate, private, max-age=0
Connection:close
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Server:thin 1.5.0 codename Knife
Set-Cookie:_rails3.website_session=biglongstringhere; path=/; expires=Sat, 02-Mar-2013 01:44:38 GMT; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie:__profilin=p%3Dt; path=/
Set-Cookie:__profilin=p%3Dt; path=/
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-MiniProfiler-Ids:[a bunch of stuff in here (this isn't the actual text)]
X-Request-Id:695da38a40064d87cbd463c83fef0a88
X-Runtime:0.034002
X-UA-Compatible:IE=Edge
```

Looking in Chrome's inspector, the file 'login' shows the Status as 'failed' but when clicking it, the Status Code is 200 OK. Another thing I've noticed is that if I put the following in before the original render call, the response displays OK, but Chrome inspector still thinks the Status response was in error (like the 1st time). Is the connection being closed before the rest of the body has a chance to be delivered? I don't understand what's wrong here.

```
render(:text => 'test', :stream => true) and return
```

As an addendum, the rails log does not show any errors. It renders everything just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have two servers; one at work and one at home. The one at home doesn't use nginx or any downstream application to communicate with Thin. Thin on its own produces an error...but using nginx in front, the files are served appropriately. Strangely though, when I don't have any streaming explicitly enabled in my rails app, the files are still served as Content Type: chunked.

Heck, even my public website is being served as chunked...but I never had streaming enabled in Rails...so that must mean the final result is chunked but not the actual rendering of the html. How can I actually test this then?

Comment: This did not answer your own question, why was it accepted?

Comment: Can't recall...I'm going to change that.